# When does an isomorphism of subgroups of a group G induce an isomorphism of their images in the homology of G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, homological-algebra

Let $G$ be a group and $M$ a $G$-module. Suppose there exist subgroups $B_0, B_1 \leq G$ and an isomorphism $\theta \colon B_0 \to B_1$. I'm interested in figuring out when there exists an isomorphism
$$ i_* H_1(B_0, M) \to i_* H_1(B_1, M), $$
between the images of $H_1(B_0, M)$ and $H_1(B_1, M)$ under the map induced by the inclusion $i \colon B_0 \hookrightarrow G$ and $i \colon B_1 \hookrightarrow G$.

**When $M \simeq \mathbb{Z}$ is the trivial $G$-module, then the result holds**. Indeed, $H_1(G, \mathbb{Z}) \simeq G/[G,G]$ is the abelianisation of $G$. If $\pi \colon G \to G/[G,G]$ is the natural quotient, then $\pi_(B_0) \simeq B_0 / B_0 \cap [G,G]$ and $\pi(B_1) \simeq B_1 / B_1 \cap [G,G]$. The isomorphism $\theta \colon B_0 \to B_1$ restricts to an isomorphism $\theta \colon B_0 \cap [G, G] \to B_1 \cap [G,G]$, since $[G,G] \leq G$ is a characteristic subgroup of $G$. Hence $\theta$ descends to an isomorphism
$$\bar{\theta} \colon B_0 / B_0 \cap [G,G] \to B_1 / B_1 \cap [G,G].$$

*I have a hunch such an isomorphism doesn't exist for a general $G$-module $M$, but I can't find a counter-example.*

Comment: You should clarify if homology means the 1st homology group. And your argument is wrong already in the case when $M={\mathbb Z}$ is the trivial $G$-module. In fact, there is no isomorphism (in general) already if $G$ is a free group on two generators $x, y$ and $B_1, B_2$ are infinite cyclic subgroups. Just take $B_1=<x>$ and $B_2=<[x,y]>$.